# Argument of type '(e: CustomEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this custom event setup, and it works with TypeScript `2.5.3`, but when I updated to `2.6.1` I get an error

```
window.addEventListener('OnRewards', (e: CustomEvent) => {
    // my code here
})
```

> [ts]
>   Argument of type '(e: CustomEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
>
> Type '(e: CustomEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListenerObject'.
>
> Property 'handleEvent' is missing in type '(e: CustomEvent) => void'.

I am not exactly sure what to do here to fix this.

Comment: What is `CustomEvent`? Maybe try with `e: Event`?

Comment: `CustomEvent` is `var event = new CustomEvent('OnRewards', { detail: data });`

Comment: If I use `Event` then it doesn't know what `detail` is inside of the function

Comment: Maybe they introduced a new bug in the latest version?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This is due to the behavior of the [`--strictFunctionTypes`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#strict-function-types) compiler flag added in TypeScript v2.6.  A function of type `(e: CustomEvent) => void` is no longer considered to be a valid instance of `EventListener`, which takes an `Event` parameter, not a `CustomEvent`.

So one way to fix it is to turn off `--strictFunctionTypes` (but don't do that, it's not safe).

---

Another way is to pass in a function that takes an `Event` and then narrows to `CustomEvent` via a type guard:

```
function isCustomEvent(event: Event): event is CustomEvent {
  return 'detail' in event;
}

window.addEventListener('OnRewards', (e: Event) => {
  if (!isCustomEvent(e))
    throw new Error('not a custom event');
  // e is now narrowed to CustomEvent ...
  // my code here 
})
```

---

A third way is to use the other overload of `addEventListener()`:

```
addEventListener<K extends keyof WindowEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: Window, ev: WindowEventMap[K]) => any, useCapture?: boolean): void;
```

If the `type` parameter is the name of a known event type (`K extends keyof WindowEventMap`) like `"onclick"`, then the `listener` function will expect its parameter to be of that narrowed event type (`WindowEventMap[K]`).  The problem is that `"OnRewards"` is not a known event type... unless you use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to *make* it known:

```
// merge into WindowEventMap
interface WindowEventMap {
    OnRewards: CustomEvent
}
```

Or, if you're inside a module (anything with `export` in it), use [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation):

```
// merge into WindowEventMap
declare global {
  interface WindowEventMap {
    OnRewards: CustomEvent
  }
}
```

Then use your code as before:

```
// no error!
window.addEventListener('OnRewards', (e: CustomEvent) => {
    // my code here
})
```

---

So, those are your options.  Which one you want to choose is up to you.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: I was able to get the second way to work, however, I like the way of the 3rd option the best. It didn't seem to work though, as I was still getting the same error message.

Comment: You might have to wrap the merge in `declare global { ... }` if your code is inside a module.

Comment: Great, just edited the answer in case anyone else runs into that problem.

Comment: +1, but I really wish you didn't start with `turn off  --strictFunctionTypes`. So many TS questions are answered with "disable the checks", and if that's the standard choice, then we could might as well just drop TS.

Comment: instead of type guard function can we check with `if(!(event instanceof CustomEvent)) throw 'not a CustomEvent'`?

Comment: If you use `document.addEventListener` instead of `window.addEventListener`, then you need to use `DocumentEventMap` instead of `WindowEventMap`.

Comment: Thank you. The second way you listed worked for me!

Answer (score 20):

Building off of [jcalz's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47171216/1103543), you can also use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to be a little cleaner:

```
window.addEventListener('OnRewards', (e: Event) => {
    const detail = (<CustomEvent>e).detail;
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not positive why all of the answers here are so convoluted. Simple typecasting can solve this:

```
window.addEventListener('OnRewards', (e: Event) => {
    const detail = (e as CustomEvent).detail
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You also have this option:

```
window.addEventListener('OnRewards', (e: CustomEvent) => {
    // your code here
} as (e: Event) => void)
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a generic function based off @jcalz's answer

```
/**
 * Checks whether an object can be safely cast to its child type
 * @param parent the object to be 'narrowly' cast down to its child type
 * @param checkForProps props which aught to be present on the child type
 */
export function isSubTypeWithProps<P, C extends P>(parent: P, ...checkForProps: (keyof C)[]): parent is C {
  return checkForProps.every(prop => prop in parent);
}

/**
 * Usage example
 */
const el = document.getElementById('test');
el.addEventListener('click', (e: Event) => {
  if (isSubTypeWithProps<Event, MouseEvent>(e, 'which')) {
    if (e.which === 1) { // primary mouse button only ('which' prop is only available on MouseEvent)
      console.log('clicked');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem with the "click" event which was unexpected because it's a native event, turns out you cannot just use document.querySelector inlined because the inferred type is `Element | null`, not `HTMLElement | null`, so you have to declare it to be an HTMLElement, meaning this fails:

```js
const ele = document.querySelector('#ele');
ele?.addEventListener('click', (event: MouseEvent) => {
   // ...
});
```

But it works fine when you declare it as an HTMLElement:

```js
const ele = document.querySelector('#ele') as HTMLElement | null;
ele?.addEventListener('click', (event: MouseEvent) => {
    // ...
});
```

I know this question is about a custom event but this is the first result when searching for the same error but on the "click" event.

Comment: just to add that `querySelector` is generic and can accept an explicit type parameter. In this case, `querySelector<HTMLElement>` returns `HTMLElement | null`

Answer (score 0):

yes and another way to satisfy your compiler is to cast the event object eg,
`yourFuctionName(e: Event){ const event = e as CustomEvent <SegmentChangeEventDetail>; console.log(event.detail)}`