# useEffect to make event handler for own defined event

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I am trying to make an event handler hook for a specific event a part of the application is throwing.

I figured like this

```
export const useMyEvent = () => {
  const myEvent = useRef<SyntheticEvent | null>();

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (!window || !window.addEventListener || myEvent) return;
      const eventListener = (event: SyntheticEvent) => myEvent.current(event);
      window.addEventListener('myEvent', eventListener);

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('myEvent', eventListener);
      };
    },
    [] // Re-run if eventName or element changes
  );
}

export default useMyEvent;
```

However I get an error "Argument of type '"myEvent"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof WindowEventMap'."

I guess I have probably made an elementary conceptual mistake here as to how to connect the event to a ref.

Comment: Maybe this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47171216/19144016) answer can help you.

Comment: thanks, that seems to be the answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ref is an object with a `.current` key, its not a function:

```
// Not myEvent.current(event)
myEvent.current = event
```

Also checking if its value is truthy is redundant, on mount, as your useEffect is defined, the ref will always hold nullish value:

```
// if (myEvent) is always truthy, myEvent.current will always be the initial value on mount
if (!window || !window.addEventListener) return;
```

Comment: In VS Code with typescript if I do this 
if (!window || !window.addEventListener || myEvent.current) return;

      const eventListener = (event: SyntheticEvent) => myEvent.current = event;

then I get no errors there, but if I leave off the check against myEvent.current I get the current is not a property on never error. 

also with those changes I still have the error "Argument of type '"myEvent"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof WindowEventMap'." for the actual add and remove event listeners.